# save print output into figure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array and I want to save the output of the print function applied to the array into a figure.
Schematically, it looks like the following:

```
print(array)

plt.savefig(output_of_print)
```

Is it possible to do it in python 3?

Comment: You could write a text on the figure. `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, `ax.text(repr(array), x, y)`, `fig.savefig(...)`.

Comment: can you say more about why you're doing this?  It's a bit unusual, which suggests there may be a better way of doing what you want

Comment: I have a dataframe. I split a column into two (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859802/display-two-dataframes-side-by-side-in-pandas) and print it. Now i want to save the output as a figure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to capture the output of `print()`, it is complicated. Instead, you should just build a string and output it to your figure instead. The easiest way to get a string representation of an array is with `str()` such as `str(array)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Do you propose array=[1, 2, 3];plt.plot(str(array))
;plt.savefig('array.png')

Comment: @Vlad I don't know matplotlib very well, so I can't answer how to add text to the plot. I'm just saying that `str(array)` gives you the text you want as a string instead of `print(array)` which only outputs text.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the output of print goes to sys.stdout. Are there any way to save sys.stdout.buffer to a figure?

Comment: @Vlad Yes, `print()` sends output to stdout. I am suggesting that instead of trying to capture the stdout buffer, just build the string directly in memory and add it to the plot using the matplotlib API. You will have to find the exact function to use from the docs.

Comment: Thank you. The following code works: fig, ax = plt.subplots();array=[1,2,3];fig=plt.text(0,1,str(array));ax.axis('off');
plt.savefig('array.png')

Comment: @Vlad Feel free to post your own answer with a more complete solution than what I wrote.

Comment: @Vlad You should write that as answer. In mean time, I will write it for you to help other.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(0, 0), dpi=80)

array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
    ]
plt.text(0,1,str(array))
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig('array.png', bbox_inches='tight')

# this is not actually needed
plt.show()
```